# Yahtzee Full House array logic javascipt

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Hey guys this is my first post on here so take it easy on me! Apologies in advance for how basic this question is as I'm a beginner. I'm in the process of self learning and googling has been my best friend so far but I'm struggling to work out what's going wrong here. Maybe it is my approach altogether...

I am building a very simple game of Yahtzee with Javascript as my first project. Most of the program works smoothly however I can't seem to get the logic right for a full house. For anyone that doesn't know Yahtzee is played with 5 dice and a full house is a pair combined with 3 of a kind so for example [1, 1, 1, 6, 6] or [4, 4, 5, 5, 5]. I have a generated array with .sort() applied so my thinking is the logic should be if index 0 = index 2 and index 3 = index 4 OR index 0 = index 1 and index 2 = index 4. I have tried with multiple nested if statements and without nested parentheses but no luck there either. I understand it must be how I've used the logical operator as the first parentheses of code in each if statement works by itself.

```js
function fullHouseFunc() {
    if ((newRoll[0] === newRoll[2])&&(newRoll[3] === newRoll[4])) {
        fullHouse.innerHTML = 25;
    } else if ((newRoll[0] === newRoll[2])&&(newRoll[3] === newRoll[4])) {
        fullHouse.innerHTML = 25;
}
};
```

Comment: The second `if` condition looks the same as the first... Did you forget to adjust it after making a copy? The logic you describe in the text is fine, but you didn't encode the second case... Also, you did not include the sorting-code. We can assume that you did that correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, just change the indices in the first if statement to 0 === 1 and 2 === 4. You had both statements checking 0 === 2 and 3 === 4:

```js
let fullHouse = document.querySelector('.fh')
let newRoll = [4,4,5,5,5] 

function fullHouseFunc() {
  if ((newRoll[0] === newRoll[1])&&(newRoll[2] === newRoll[4])) {
    fullHouse.innerHTML = 25;
  } else if ((newRoll[0] === newRoll[2])&&(newRoll[3] === newRoll[4])) {
    fullHouse.innerHTML = 25;
  }
}

fullHouseFunc()
```

```html
<div class='fh'></div>
```